# While serving Hartgen, was Gillete brainwashed by magic or chemicals, or he was just in shock from the near death?

Tags: hitsugi-no-chaika

In episode 8 of the second season (*Hitsugi no Chaika: Avenging Battle*), Gillete didn't recognize his subordinates until...

> ... Vivi was forced to cut off Gillete's hand in order to prevent him from killing Nikolai. Due to the pain, he snapped out and regained his memories.

Did Guy brainwash Gillete, or was he just amnesiac?